# String split at second delimiter in notepad++

Tags: regex

I have a string in second column like the following in tab file:

```
Apple  Fruit_00001_gxw@1983
Peach  Fruit_00002_gxw@1968
Berry  Fruit_00003_f@1973
```

I tried replacing in Notepad++ with replace by regular expression

> \_\w+. with nothing

Here it considers _00001 also as a word. I misjudged, it would be treated as number. How can I modify it to split at second delimiter ? So that the output is,

```
Apple  Fruit_00001
Peach  Fruit_00002
Berry  Fruit_00003
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `\w`? Or just anchor it with `$`. `_\w+$`

Comment: `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (and really shouldn't since it confuses so many people)

Comment: Also from the small extract you posted you might be able to use Notepad++'s [Column Edition Mode](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html), which would save you the hassle of using regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\w` matches letters, digits and `_`, that is why it matches more than you need.

You may fix it using

```
_[^\s_]+$
```

**Details**

- `_` - an underscore
- `[^\s_]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and `_`
- `$` - end of line

[image]

An alternative solution that allows you to detect substrings of `_[letters]@[digits]` scheme is

```
_\pL+@\d+
```

that matches `_`, then 1+ letters, `@`, and then 1+ digits.

Comment: I think, since the "Fruit_00001", string length is 11 and consistent. Why not just write it to shorten the string to 11 characters and remove rest of them?.

Comment: @Arun, if the requirement is like "keep the first 11 chars and remove the rest", then just use `^(.{11}).*` => `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

***Solution 1st:*** Using `gensub` in `awk`:

```
awk '{print gensub(/([^_]*)_([^_]*)(.*)/,"\\1_\\2",1)}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Apple  Fruit_00001
Peach  Fruit_00002
Berry  Fruit_00003
```

***Solution 2nd:*** As per OP since 2nd column's length is fixed so by length vice solution.

```
awk '{print $1,substr($2,1,11)}'   Input_file
```